# Find the sum of the series .

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

The general term of the series is 
$\sum_{r=0}^{100}\binom{500}{r}\binom{500-r}{400}2^{100-r}$

What I tried to think that this series was an expansion for a series inside a series but the thing that i found out is that I have to find the sum of a series which stops at 100 but runs till the power of 500 .

Comment: Use $\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$ and play around a bit to find $\binom{100}{r}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is equal to $\sum_{r=0}^{100}\frac{500!}{r!(500-r)!}\frac{(500-r)!}{400!(100-r)!}2^{100-r}=\frac{500!}{400!100!}\sum_{r=0}^{100}\frac{100!}{r!(100-r)!}2^{100-r}={500\choose 100}3^{100}$.

Comment: All too easy.  +1.